# Anaconda Spyder integrated IPython display for dataframes

Tags: ipython, spyder

The new anaconda spyder has an integrated iPython console.  I really dislike the way dataframes are displayed in this console.  There are some border graphics around the dataframe and resizing that occurs with window resizing that make it difficult to examine the contents.  In addition, often for large dataframes if one just types the variable name, we can only see a XX rows x YY columns display, not a display of the top corner of the dataframe.

How can I reset the dataframe display so that it displays the way a standard iPython (or iPython QT) console would display a dataframe, i.e. with no graphics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The development version of Spyder has a Pandas Dataframe editor (and an numpy array editor, up to 3d). You can run this from source or wait for the next release, 2.3.1.

This is probably more adequate to edit or visualize dataframe than using the embedded qtconsole.

Comment: Your answer is unrelated. He is referring to a completely different issue.

Comment: It is related. The qt console embedded in Spyder is not very adequate to display large dataframes. Spyder has a better tool for that, the dataframe editor.

Comment: Ok, I thought he was referring to this issue that I'm having https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818216/how-can-i-remove-borders-from-display-of-dataframe-in-ipython-qtconsole-anacond