# How can I remove borders from display of dataframe in iPython QtConsole (Anaconda)?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, dataframe, anaconda

I need to launch iPython QT console from the Editor window on Anaconda. But I really dislike how it displays the dataframes with this weird border (Pic #1):

[image: Pic #1]

How can I make it look normal, like this (Pic #2):

[image: Pic #2]

System Information:

- Anaconda 2.0.1
- Python 2.7.7
- iPyth on 2.2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn off the pretty-printing that is the default by the following:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)
```

To make it permanent you can make the modifications in your IPython config files, though where exactly I'm not sure.

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution that does not require importing pandas.